# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

i have tried with many things but i am not able to Get notifications in devices.

i also tried with below thing.

In the Properties pane, set the Build Action Select google-services.json in the Solution Explorer window.

In the Properties pane, set the Build Action to GoogleServicesJson (if the GoogleServicesJson build action is not shown, save and close the Solution, then reopen it):to GoogleServicesJson

Notification was working before, but after I update the xamarin forms to 2.5.0.280555 and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.42.1021.1, it stopped working .

Comment: It happens sometime because package name not matching in google-services.json

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure:

1. Package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` is identical to one in the `google-services.json`
2. `google-services.json` build action is set to `GoogleServicesJson`
3. After step 2 restart your IDE & clean & rebuild
4. Explicitly call `FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);` in `MainActivity.OnCreate` just before the `LoadApplication(..)`

Comment: Thank you very much!  steps 1 and 2,  first time seeing these instructions anywhere, most information elsewhere just says "add `google-services.json` to the platform/android folder" and that's it.  (smacking my forehead), and it's hit-or-miss whether or not you get clues about step 4.

Answer (score 33):

For me, none of the solutions worked that were given anywhere. Only this worked.
Just had to downgrade my google services from 4.1.0 to 4.0.0

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha08'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    /*classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' <-- this was the problem */
}
```

So if you have updated the google services, just try to downgrade or change to an older version.
Hope it helps

Comment: In my case I had to upgrade to com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

Answer (score 24):

Add the plugin to the build.gradle (app level)

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I was able to run my app with Firebase just fine but after force closing and restarting I was getting this crash. Adding the apply plugin at the bottom of my build.gradle fixed the crash.

Answer (score 3):

for me, that happen when I forgot add the second plugin in the app module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin
```

after add this plug in, you can try the other's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade  `com.google.gms:google-services` to latest version, it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade

> com.google.gms:google-services

to latest version, it will be solved.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i've recently had this problem and found a solution that worked for me:

i've been developing for net7.0-android33.0 and i just realized that I had added in my .csproj an specific PropertyGroup Condition for that targetFramework where **i had set a different ApplicationId**.

My Google-Services.json was created with the previous ApplicationId so i've generated a new one in Firebase with the correct ApplicationId and it worked.

Maybe it's a bit silly but i've been stuck on this for a couple days so it may help someone

Answer (score 0):

In my case it fails before reaching OnCreate(), for `CrossFirebaseCrashlytics.Current.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);`

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .RegisterFirebaseServices()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        #if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
        #endif

        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebaseServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, _) =>
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity, CreateCrossFirebaseSettings())));
            CrossFirebaseCrashlytics.Current.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => CrossFirebaseAuth.Current);
        return builder;
    }

    private static CrossFirebaseSettings CreateCrossFirebaseSettings()
    {
        return new CrossFirebaseSettings(isAuthEnabled: true,
        isCloudMessagingEnabled: true, isAnalyticsEnabled: true);
    }
}
```