# (.NET MAUI) Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.dev.testapp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I am having issues doing anything with Firebase, I have followed about 4 different guides online and I am still getting the error listed above. Please see my project and resource details below

#### MauiProgram.cs

```
            builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
                events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, _) => FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(activity)));
            });
```

#### .csproj Application Id and Google Service Json Refr

```
<!-- App Identifier -->
<ApplicationId>com.dev.testapp</ApplicationId>

<!-- This file is in the root of my project not Platforms/Android/ -->
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In the google-services.json file, the `package_name` and `bundle_id` are the same and also match the `applicationId` I stated above. Any help is much appreciated this is frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar issue on Github.[Default FirebaseApp is not initialized #357](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/357). Many comment suggests to set the Build action of google-services.json to **GoogleServicesJson**. So you may install Xamarin.GooglePlayservices.Base Nuget. Don't forget to clean your project.

Also, you could check this thread: [Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49452159/20118901). EvZ's answer give some suggestions.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: will try the now, the only concern is that these posts are geared towards Xamarin.Forms rather than .NET MAUI.

Comment: Yeah. I just install this Nuget in Maui and it could build successfully

Comment: Thx. That's was my problem. It works fine now on MAUI! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody finds this and is using .net7.0 as well. I could solve it with this website.

[https://dev.to/vhugogarcia/firebase-analytics-in-net-maui-4p6d][1]

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">
      <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Core" Version="121.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Basically installed Xamarin.Firebase.Core and initialized it in MauiProgram.cs

by adding the method:

```
private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebase(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, bundle) => {
                Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(activity);
            }));
#endif
        });

        return builder;
    }
```

Then on the static CreateMauiApp method register the Firebase Services:

```
builder.RegisterFirebase();
```

Comment: didn't work for me, using  net8.0 if it matters